# How to rotate an static image in HTML

Tags: android, static, html, rotation

in my application, i need a static image to be rotated in HTML. Please help me for that

Comment: rotated as in animated rotation? 90 degree rotation?

Comment: Please don’t ask the same question multiple times just because you didn’t got an answer yet. I closed your former question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250434 in favor of this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use imagemagik or a similar program on your server to dynamically generate it. You might also be able to do something with javascript. I found a nice link for a jQuery rotate function: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: Thank you.Ya, i need to do in javascript only....But how to run this one, where should i place my image ???